# What is the point of having more than one Mii?

Tags: miitomo

In Miitomo, you can register up to 101 Miis (according to it's in-game FAQ).

What is the point of having more than your avatar? The other's don't seem to hang around your room, even randomly, and they don't interact with your friend's Miis either.

Why would I add more Miis, either by creation or QR code?

Comment: You can use them in Miifotos as additional characters, but I haven't seen any other use for them.

Comment: Maybe features that haven't been implemented yet? The shortest stretch I could see would be the QR thing being useful if you wanted to have a Nintendo character Mii (say, a Mario Mii), who answered all the silly questions that Miitomo offered him in a characteristically silly fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add other Miis to your account, they will occasionally show up in background places while you are playing Miitomo.

So far, I have noticed that they can appear:

- At the register when checking out from purchases
- In the 'loading' screen before the game is booted up
- In Miitomo Drop as Miis that you can drop to try and get special items
- As additional characters in MiiFotos

Other than that, you cannot interact with them in any significant way.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Added. Honestly I entirely overlooked the fact you could add them to photos.